# TomEE service doesn't start on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: service, windows-7-x64, apache-tomee

I installed TomEE on Windows 7 (64 bit) as service.
Manually starting (by means of start.bat) works fine, but when trying to start the service, I get:

"Windows could not start the TomEE on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service specific error code 4."

The log entry mentioned by the error message says:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
        <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7024</EventID> 
        <Version>0</Version> 
        <Level>2</Level> 
        <Task>0</Task> 
        <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
        <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-06-29T04:15:32.139508900Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>96150</EventRecordID> 
        <Correlation /> 
        <Execution ProcessID="896" ThreadID="7752" /> 
        <Channel>System</Channel> 
        <Computer>...(I removed this string)...</Computer> 
        <Security /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="param1">TomEE</Data> 
        <Data Name="param2">%%4</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the service. The symptom persists.

The service description is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TomEE]
"Type"=dword:00000010
"Start"=dword:00000002
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"ImagePath"=hex(2):45,00,3a,00,5c,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,77,00,61,00,72,00,\
  65,00,5c,00,61,00,70,00,61,00,63,00,68,00,65,00,2d,00,74,00,6f,00,6d,00,65,\
  00,65,00,2d,00,77,00,65,00,62,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,\
  5c,00,62,00,69,00,6e,00,5c,00,54,00,6f,00,6d,00,45,00,45,00,2e,00,61,00,6d,\
  00,64,00,36,00,34,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,2f,00,52,00,53,00,\
  2f,00,2f,00,54,00,6f,00,6d,00,45,00,45,00,00,00
"DisplayName"="TomEE"
"DependOnService"=hex(7):54,00,63,00,70,00,69,00,70,00,00,00,41,00,66,00,64,00,\
  00,00,00,00
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TomEE\Parameters]
```

which displays in Regedit GUI as:

- ImagePath = E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\bin\TomEE.amd64.exe //RS//TomEE

  DependOnService = Tcpip Afd

ProcMon's logfile with the filters:

- include

  - ProcessName contains Tom
- exclude

  - Result is SUCCESS
  - Result is END OF FILE
  - Result is NO MORE FILEs

is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<procmon>
    <processlist>
        <!-- removed to shorten the file for the forum -->
    <processlist>
    <eventlist>
    <!-- shortened file by removing <Time_of_Day> and same elements from every
        <event>
            <ProcessIndex>520</ProcessIndex>
            <Process_Name>TomEE.amd64.exe</Process_Name>
            <PID>8088</PID>
        </event>
    -->
        <event>
            <Operation>QueryInformationVolume</Operation>
            <Path>C:</Path>
            <Result>BUFFER OVERFLOW</Result>
            <Detail>VolumeCreationTime: 02-Jun-14 11:15:49 PM, VolumeSerialNumber: 28EB-3828, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: WINȈ</Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>QueryInformationVolume</Operation>
            <Path>E:</Path>
            <Result>BUFFER OVERFLOW</Result>
            <Detail>VolumeCreationTime: 02-Jun-14 08:32:24 AM, VolumeSerialNumber: 4881-ADFA, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: DATȈ</Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTDLL.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\APISETSCHEMA.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOCALE.NLS</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\bin\TomEE.amd64.exe</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCRT.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SECHOST.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GDI32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LPK.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USP10.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\GLOBALIZATION\SORTING\SORTDEFAULT.NLS</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGFILES\APACHE\TOMEE.2015-06-30.LOG</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\SERVER\JVM.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NSI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\VERIFY.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\JAVA.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TZRES.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\INSTRUMENT.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\LIB\OPENEJB-JAVAAGENT.JAR</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFile</Operation>
            <Path>C:\Windows\TEMP\HSPERFDATA_LPV0RAD1346E2$\7468</Path>
            <Result>NAME NOT FOUND</Result>
            <Detail>Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Execute/Traverse, Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Non-Directory File, Complete If Oplocked, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a</Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\ZIP.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\LIB\META-INDEX</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\ENDORSED\ANNOTATION-API.JAR</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\ENDORSED\JAXB-API.JAR</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\LIB\RT.JAR</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLE32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROFAPI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\LIB\EXT\META-INDEX</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\LIB\TZMAPPINGS</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\LIB\TZDB.DAT</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\EN-US\KERNELBASE.DLL.MUI</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTDLL.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\APISETSCHEMA.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\bin\TomEE.amd64.exe</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCRT.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SECHOST.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
       <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GDI32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LPK.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USP10.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\SERVER\JVM.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NSI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\VERIFY.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\JAVA.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\INSTRUMENT.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>E:\software\java\JRE8-64\BIN\ZIP.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLE32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROFAPI.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFileMapping</Operation>
            <Path>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL</Path>
            <Result>FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS</Result>
            <Detail>SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: </Detail>
        </event>
        <event>
            <Operation>CreateFile</Operation>
            <Path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\SupTab\SEARCH~2.DLL</Path>
            <Result>NAME NOT FOUND</Result>
            <Detail>Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a</Detail>
        </event>
        <!-- removed further events to meet the forum's size limit -->
    </eventlist>
</procmon>
```

Comment: Execute `net helpmsg 4` on the command line, this will give you an idea what this error is about. On my (non-Englisch) Windows this returns something like "the system was unable to open this file". Perhaps it is a good idea to run procmon.exe from live.sysinternals.com while you try to start the service, it will show you what is going wrong.

Comment: Please post the definition of your service, you will find it in the registry below HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<My Service>. Did you try installing into a directory without spaces, for example c:\tomee ?

Comment: The procmon logfile is huge, even after filtering... The service definition: `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TomEE]`
`"Type"=dword:00000010`
`"Start"=dword:00000002`
`"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001`
`"ImagePath"=hex(2):...`
`"DisplayName"="TomEE"`
`"DependOnService"=hex(7):...`
`"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TomEE\Parameters]`

`<br/> where **DependOnService**=`Tcpip
Afd

` and **ImagePath**=`E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\bin\TomEE.amd64.exe //RS//TomEE`

Comment: The procmon logfile is huge, even after filtering... The service definition: `**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TomEE]**`
`"Type"=dword:**00000010**`
`"Start"=dword:**00000002**`
`"ErrorControl"=dword:**00000001*`
`"ImagePath"=hex(2):**E:\software\apache-tomee-webprofile\bin\TomEE.amd64.exe //RS//TomEE**`
`"DisplayName"=**"TomEE"**`
`"DependOnService"=hex(7):**Tcpip Afd**`
`"ObjectName"=**"LocalSystem"**`

`**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\TomEE\Parameters]**`

Comment: Sorry, how can I put the exported .reg file in the comment?

Comment: don't use a comment for this, edit your question and paste the text there, then mark it as code to format it properly

Comment: Have you checked if the executable is in the place mentioned ? Permissions correct ? In the procmon: which lines are not tagged with success ?

Comment: I'm surprised that Windows system files (WSOCK32.dll, WINMM.dll, VERSION.dll, MSVCR100.dll) are searched in the BIN directory of TomEE. I just copied them there (from System32), but the symptom remains (Error 4).

Comment: I think that is normal because before trying the defined search path the current working directory i searched for these files. If all paths checked for the dlls return a not found it makes sense to copy files or enhance the search path. Did you try to start tomee directly by using tomee.amd64.exe ? As far as I remember the service has a test configuration that allows you to do so

Comment: Did you find this link ? It mentions a rather similar problem http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-as-a-Service-Windows-7-x64-td4662996.html

Comment: According [link](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-as-a-Service-Windows-7-x64-tt4662996.html#a4663170), I changed registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\TomEE\Parameters\Java ` value from `jvm="auto"` to `jvm="E:\software\java\jdk8-64"`. Now I get error 1 (Incorrect function).

Comment: why don't you set the complete path to the jvm.dll ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but the symptoms remain unchanged. I also re-installed JDK and JRE in standard directories, also without changing the results.